# Does using tcp guarantee it will be sent/received?

Tags: delphi, tcp, winsock

I've been working on a simple winsock file transfer for a friend and me to share files without needing to upload to mediafire everytime.But a problem I have ran into is/was(depending on how you see my current solution) I couldn't send the file without corrupting it.
Currently my solution for sending/receiving is:

```
procedure SenBuf(var buf;count:dword);
var
  a, c: pointer;
  cousend, tmp, left: dword;
begin
  a := @buf;
  cousend := 0;
  left := count;
  repeat
    c := ptr(dword(a) + cousend);
    tmp := Send(hSocket, c^, left, 0);
    inc(cousend, tmp);
    dec(left, tmp);
  until cousend = count;
end;

procedure RecvBuf(var buf;count:dword);
var
  a, c: pointer;
  cousend, tmp, left: dword;
begin
  a := @buf;
  cousend := 0;
  left := count;
  repeat
    c := ptr(dword(a) + cousend);
    tmp := Recv(hSocket, c^, left, 0);
    inc(cousend, tmp);
    dec(left, tmp);
  until cousend = count;
end;
```

but I'm using a tcp connection,why would I need to check for the bytes being sent/received and resend them?
(I know the reason is packet dropping as it works perfectly on localhost).

how it listens for connections:

```
 hServer := Socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,6);
 sAddr.sin_family      := AF_INET;
 sAddr.sin_port        := htons(wPort);
 sAddr.sin_addr.S_addr := INADDR_ANY;
 Bind(hServer, sAddr, SizeOf(sAddr));
 winsock.Listen(hServer,3);
 while not(Self.Terminated) do begin
   iSize:=SizeOf(cAddr);
   hClient:=Accept(hServer,@cAddr,@iSize);
   if (hClient <> INVALID_SOCKET) then begin
     sleep(50);
     Client := TClient.Create(True);
     Clients.Add(Client);
     with Client do begin
       hHost := inet_ntoa(cAddr.sin_addr);
       Resume();
     end;
 /// incomplete code?
```

server - Client:

```
    procedure TClient.Execute;
    var
      mode: integer;
      bytBuf: Array[0..255] of Char;
      iRecv: Integer;
    begin
      inherited;
      mode := 0;
      ZeroMemory(@bytbuf, 256);
      ioctlsocket(hSocket, FionBio, mode);
      repeat
        iRecv := Recv(hSocket, bytBuf, 256, 0);
        if (iRecv <= 0) and (iRecv <> EWOULDBLOCK) then 
          break;
        if not(bytbuf[0]=#0) then
          Process(bytBuf);
        ZeroMemory(@bytbuf,256);
      until 1=2;
```

client - client:

```
procedure Start;
var
  mode: integer;
begin
  repeat
    mode := 0;//blocking mode.
    hSocket := Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 6);
    ioctlsocket(hSocket, FionBio, mode);
    Addr.sin_family := AF_INET;
    Addr.sin_port := htons(hport);
    Addr.sin_addr.S_addr := INET_ADDR(pchar(GetIPFromHost(cHost)));
    if (winsock.Connect(hSocket,Addr, SizeOf(Addr)) = 0) then begin
      SenStr('+');
      WaitForServAndProcess;
    end;
  Sleep(20000);
  lping:=GetTickCount;
  until 1 = 2;
end;
```

would someone kindly tell me my mistake?Or send me a really nice winsock tutorial?(doesn't have to be spoonfed).

Comment: I think you're trying too hard to solve problems already solved by others in libraries such as Indy, my suggestion is to stop wasting time on this and use that.

Comment: I would prefer to understand the reason why it occurs rather than just using someone else's work :/

Comment: @user0 well, from what I know, TCP guarantees that the packets arrive to the destination **and** in the sent order so long as the connection does not experience some "extraordinary situations"(i.e. disconnected for too long) -- not a network specialist, sorry for not bringing in much value ):

Comment: You'd prefer to understand the reason why *what* occurs, exactly? The only real question you've asked here is why you need to check how many bytes were sent or received. You followed that with lots of code and asked what your mistake was, without actually describing why you think there's a mistake.

Comment: Why I think there is a mistake is that when I use my wan to test,it doesn't send the data without corrupting it.On localhost=>no problems and I transferred a 1GB file(game) perfectly without a single error.

Comment: If you want to understand how it works, use an existing, **working** library and read it's source code. There are several to choose from that are free with source. This is just re-inventing the wheel for absolutely no reason except to re-invent the wheel. I can think of many better ways to spend my time than manually implementing functionality that's freely available and tested. :-)

Comment: would you name a few so I can check them out?Also ontopic:so there are problems with using winsock to transfer files?It's not just me failing at something?

Comment: @user0 - sounds like you are trying to reinvent the wheel - for the 1000th time...

Comment: Yes, `SOCK_STREAM` is **reliable delivery** protocol, this means what receiving host will reply to the sending host with `ACK`s. Failure to receive an ACK in the timely fashion can be detected (and you;ll get a socket error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are corrupting your file data because you are not doing any error checking when calling WinSock's `send()` and `recv()` functions, eg:

```
procedure SenBuf(var buf; count:dword);
var
  a: PByte;
  tmp: Integer;
begin
  a := PByte(@buf);
  while count > 0 do begin
    tmp := send(hSocket, a^, count, 0);
    if tmp = SOCKET_ERROR then begin
      if WSAEWOULDBLOCK = WSAGetLastError() then begin
        // optionally use select() to detect when the socket is writable again...
        Continue;
      end;
      // error!!! Stop sending...
      Exit;
    end;
    inc(a, tmp);
    dec(count, tmp);
  end;
end;

procedure RecvBuf(var buf; count:dword);
var
  a: PByte;
  tmp: Integer;
begin
  a := PByte(@buf);
  while count > 0 do begin
    tmp := recv(hSocket, a^, count, 0);
    if tmp = SOCKET_ERROR then begin
      if WSAEWOULDBLOCK = WSAGetLastError() then begin
        // optionally use select() to detect when the socket is readable again...
        Continue;
      end;
      // error!!! Stop reading...
      Exit;
    end;
    if tmp = 0 then begin
      // disconnected!!! Stop reading...
      Exit;
    end;
    inc(a, tmp);
    dec(count, tmp);
  end;
end;
```

.

```
procedure TClient.Execute;
var
  mode: integer;
  bytBuf: Array[0..255] of Char;
  iRecv: Integer;
begin
  mode := 0;
  ioctlsocket(hSocket, FionBio, mode);
  repeat
    iRecv := recv(hSocket, @bytBuf[0], SizeOf(bytBuf), 0);
    if iRecv <= 0 then begin
      // error or disconnected!!! Stop reading...
      Exit;
    end;
    Process(bytBuf, iRecv);
  until False;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you so much,I never did any error checking,but guess that's something I should have done.No wonder why it failed to send it.